# MFC Bluetooth : BluetoothRegisterForAuthentication doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, bluetooth

I'm working with VS 2008 with Windows SDK 7.1 installed.
To pair a BT device with my application I use Windows BT APIs.
The APIs I'm using are BluetoothRegisterForAuthentication and BluetoothAuthenticateDevice.

I compiled the application on Windows XP and it works fine on the OS.
The problem happens when I run the application on Windows 7 machine.
BluetoothRegisterForAuthentication returns error code 1783 which is RPC_X_BAD_STUB_DATA.

If I compile the same code on Windows 7 it works fine with the OS but it fails to start the application.

Same thing happens if I run the application, which is compiled with Windows7, on Windows 8.

I don't understand simply the Windows operating system and development tool(VS 2008 in my case) works like this.

Please give me any advice. I need to make the application work on Windows XP, Vista,7 and 8. And I'm considering build multiple exe file for each OS.
Belows are my code.

```
bool BluetoothAuthCallback(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO  pDeviceInfo)
{
DWORD dwRet;
CLogFile * m_pLog = CLogFile::getInstance();

dwRet = BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponse(NULL, pDeviceInfo, L"0000");
if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return 1;
}
return 1;
}

int pairBluetooth(BTH_ADDR bthAddr)
{
CLogFile * m_pLog = CLogFile::getInstance();
SOCKADDR_BTH sa = { 0 };
int sa_len = sizeof(sa);
DWORD dwRet;
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO  btdi = {0};
HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION hRegHandle = 0;

btdi.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
btdi.Address.ullLong = bthAddr;
btdi.ulClassofDevice = 0;
btdi.fConnected = false;
btdi.fRemembered = false;
btdi.fAuthenticated = false;

dwRet = BluetoothRegisterForAuthentication(&btdi, &hRegHandle, (PFN_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK)&BluetoothAuthCallback, NULL);
if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    TRACE("BluetoothRegisterForAuthentication ret %d\n", dwRet);
}

dwRet = BluetoothAuthenticateDevice(NULL, NULL, &btdi, L"0000", 4);
if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    TRACE("BluetoothAuthenticateDevice ret %d\n", dwRet);
}

Sleep(1000);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault in building install packages.
The package includes bt related system file.
Actually there was an warning message about it. But I was simply ignoring it.
Just removing the file from the package make it works fine with other OS.